# How can I get ffmpeg to autorotate input files while concatenating?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using the following command to concatenate a list of `.mov` files:

```
ffmpeg -safe 0 -f concat -i files  -vcodec copy -acodec copy merged.mov
```

This works insofar as the files get concatenated... but the files contain rotation metadata (they are from an iPhone) which I'd like ffmpeg to respect so that `merged.mov` shows all the constituent videos with the correct orientation.

I'm using ffmpeg version 2.8.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1.

Comment: Not possible, at present. Consider a wish request at trac,ffmpeg.org

Comment: @Gyan: Is there a workaround such as rotating each individually first, then concatenating?

Comment: Yes, but you'll have to do that yourself.